# android avd No protocol specified

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm a newbee to android development
I want to set up a virtual enmulation android device, but there is such a problem, what is wrong with this? Thanks

```
[root@goeland MyFirstApp]# android avd
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.sdkman2.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.createShell(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:160)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.sdkman2.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:131)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:110)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:367)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:300)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:120)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this same error when trying to invoke `android` via SSH without forwarding X (with the `-x` flag).

Thus, if you're experiencing this issue and you're accessing a remote machine by `ssh user@remotemachine`, you need to forward X11 by using `ssh -X user@remotemachine`.

If this isn't your issue and you're still having it, could you provide more information to help us help you? Otherwise, could you contribute back and share how you fixed it?